# Validation are dissapearing while deployment in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis, visual-studio-express

I have a asp.net validation in test box when i debug and run in vs2008 web developer edition is working fine.

But when i display the code in the production server by copy pasting the code in web root folder its not working.

I am developing the application using vs2008 web developer edition in windows 2003 server, i am deploying the code on another windows 2003 server using IIS.

Is this a problem with .js file? or a patch in the windows 2003 server? or a IIS version problem ?

Comment: If you right-click your web site in Solution Explorer, do you see a Publish command? That's what you should use to publish your web site, not copy and paste.

Also, do make sure that ASP.NET is installed and configured on the server.

Comment: Publish is not available in the express edition iirc

Comment: I have used the publish option; still its not working

Comment: You need to provide more info.  Make a small sample prototype which demonstrates the problem, post your observed result and any errors you might have gotten.

Comment: when i drag a text box and a required field validation assigned to the text box and debug and run the web page works fine. 
If i copy paste the same code in the webroot folder of another server.
and access the live link; and when i put no text in textbox ..the data is not validating at all ..it is submitting

Answer (score 0):

Please check the CauseValidation property of surrounding controls. Is any of them set to False by mistake.